# Does there exist a numerical base such that $9 + 10 = 21$ is true?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

We can set up the equation as follows:

$$9 \text{ (base b)} + 10 \text{ (base b)} =21 \text{ (base b)} $$

And rewrite as $9_b +10_b = 21_b$ for a more compact notation.

I can see that the base, $b$, must be greater than $9$.

Is there a way to set up an equation to solve for $b$ given these restraints?

Comment: Nope: $10_b$ plus any single digit number $x_b$ is always $1x_b,$ there's no way around it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In base $b$, the numeral "10" denotes the value $b$, while "21" is $2b + 1$.  So, you just need to solve:

$$9 + b = 2b + 1$$

From here, ordinary algebra gives $b = 8$, aka [octal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal).

Except that the conventional octal notation only uses the digits 0-7, *not* 9 (which would be written as "11").  So if you enforce this rule, there is *no* base in which "9 + 10 = 21".